# Google Maps with custom map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline

Is there a way to display a custom map using the **Google Maps API** and draw **polylines** on it using **(x, y) coordinates**? I am not interested in geolocation, since I just want to create a demo scenario for an indoor navigation app.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs you can use [Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay) that allows you to load your own map using the tile engine of the map or [Ground Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/groundoverlay) that draws a fixed image on a given coordinate.

As both are map overlays you can still draw polylines, polygons, markers, ... on the map

Comment: would you please send some source code for tile overlay for multi zoom level? how to add map in tile overlay?